# How to display each set of data in a List in a new row?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` where I want to load data as strings from a List.
I want the data to be loaded horizontally (go to next column) instead of vertically (go to new row), for each set in the list.
This `DataGridView` has a fix number of Columns and since it is a List, the number of rows depends on the number of sets in the List.

My issue with my code is, instead of adding a new row for the subsequent set of the List, it just replaces the first set of data in the List.
So how do I display each set of data in a new row?

My code:

```
private void Form1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 9;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach (string item in Class1.DTG2_list)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            if (item == string.Empty)
                dataGridView2.Rows[counter].Cells[i].Value = false.ToString();
            else
                dataGridView2.Rows[counter].Cells[i].Value = item;
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show a `List<string>` in `DataGridView` in a specific number of columns, you can create a `DataTable` having that specific number of columns and then add your data to `DataTable` and show them in `DataGridView`.

In the following example, I assume I have a `List<string>` and I want to show the list in 4 columns in `DataGridView`:

```
//My test data
var list = Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1).Select(c => (char)c).ToList();

//Create DataTable
var columnsCount = 4;
var datatable = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++)
    datatable.Columns.Add($"C{i + 1}");

//Convert List<string> to DataTable having 4 columns
list.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / columnsCount).ToList()
    .ForEach(x => datatable.Rows.Add(x.Select(m => m.Value).Cast<object>().ToArray()));

//Show data in DataGridView
dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
```

[image]

Comment: HI @ Reza Aghaei. Thanks for the solution, it works perfectly if only 1 List is involved. But may I know, which part of your code "controls" the position where the new row is added? The thing is, I would want to combine multiple `Lists`  into one major `List`. This major `List` if I were to use your code, will cause the subsequent set of data to be added from the top instead of the bottom. Like instead of adding more rows below, it will add more row at the top. So the first set of data will eventually be in the last row of `datagridview`. I am new to this so hope to get some pointers.

Comment: You have some options. As an option you can combine the new list with the old list and use above solution again. Another option is creating a new datatable for new list and insert the rows before rows on the existing datatable.